# Which cancer cell lines do not increase glucose uptake in comparison with their wild type analogues?

Tags: biochemistry

I heard that some cell lines which already have a high glucose influx do not increase it upon altering to a cancer phenotype. However, I cannot find any supporting references.

Comment: Where did you hear?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.